# Is there a Way to Map Child Elements Child in react using React.Children

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

So I was just Trying a way to map the child component send to me but my child component have further childs in them i.e. some of the `<h1></h1>` tags so is there a way to further map these `<h1></h1>` elements in the code.

> Parent Component

```
var ParentComp = function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <SomeComponent name="Dev">
                <div>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                    <h1>DEV</h1>
                </div>
            </SomeComponent>
        </div>
    )
}
```

> ChildComponent

```
var SomeComponent = function(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>            
            <div>
                {React.Children.map(props.children, function(child) {
                    return (
                        React.Children.map(function(children) {
                            return (
                                <fieldset {...children.props}>
                                    <legend>{React.cloneElement(children)}</legend>
                                </fieldset>
                            )
                        })
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

what i want is to map those `<h1></h1>` tags but this code is only mapping the div.

Comment: What is exactly the child components send to you ? Is that you have a list in parent that you want to inject to the children? Or is there the elements you want to forcefully put them into the child (`SomeComponent`)?

Comment: `SomeComponent` is my child component and it have some children props with `div` which contain further child's `h1`. What i want is a loop to set `H1` in `feildset` but above code is setting `div` in the fieldset so is there a way to map the `h1`?